# How to get mean and CI of fitted values in GAM

Tags: r, predict, data-fitting, gam, mgcv

I have a dataset:

```
#
# Producing some data
#
set.seed(82)
library(simstudy)

def <- defData(varname = "trx", dist = "binary", formula = 0.5, id = "cid")
def <- defData(def, varname = "baseDBP", dist = "normal", formula = "70+2.3*trx", variance = 40)
def <- defData(def, varname = "Y0", dist = "normal", formula = "1.8*trx", variance = 40)
def <- defData(def, varname = "Y1", dist = "normal", formula = "(Y0*-1.7) * (.8*trx)", variance = 50)
def <- defData(def, varname = "Y2", dist = "normal", formula = "Y0 * 1.1", variance = 50)
dtstudy <- genData(4000, def)
dtstudy$trx <- factor(dtstudy$trx, levels = c(0 , 1), labels = c("None", "Agent x"))
```

I perform GAM and plot:

```
#
# Analyzing by GAM
#
library(MASS)
library(mgcv)
library(visreg)
library(ggplot2)

adj.gam <-gam(baseDBP ~ trx + s(Y0) + s(Y1) + s(Y2), data=dtstudy)
p.gam <- visreg(adj.gam, "trx", ylab="", xlab="", overlay=TRUE, gg=TRUE)
p.gam
```

I get this plot:

[image]

Now, I would like to know `mean` and `CI` of the fitted values for both groups "None" and "Agent x".

I cannot find useful information in `?predict.gam`

Comment: Isn't what you need in `summary(adj.gam)`?

Comment: I'm having trouble interpreting the summary results. 
`Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  70.0966     0.1411  496.74   <2e-16 ***
trxAgent x    2.1786     0.2016   10.81   <2e-16 *** ` 
From here, what is the mean and SE of none and agentx? Thx

Comment: None is the reference level. So its value should be the intercept. Agent x's mean is 2.1786 greater than the intercept.